# Able to run POST and GET on local machine, but not when deployed to heroku

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

When running my app on my localhost, I'm able to do a GET and POST request to my mongo database (mongo atlas); however, when I deploy to heroku (removing my proxy), I get a 404 whenever I try and use my GET or POST routes.

I've removed the proxy.  I've white-listed all addresses in mongoDB Atlas. I've added:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

I've tried a static.json file.

Here's my server.js:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const connectDB = require('./config/db');
    const path = require('path');

    const app = express();

    // Connect Database
    connectDB();

    // Init Middleware
    app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

    // Define Routes
    app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
    app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
    app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
    app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));

    // Serve static assets in production
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // Set static folder
      app.use(express.static('client/build'));

      app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
      });
    }

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Here's my routes/index.js

```
    const router = require("express").Router();

    router.use("/api", require("./api"))

    module.exports = router;
```

Here's my routes/api/index.js

```
    const router = require("express").Router();

    router.use("/users", require("./users"))
    router.use("/story", require("./story"))

    module.exports = router
```

Here's an example of the routes inside my api/story.js

```
    const router = require("express").Router();
    const storyController = require("../../controllers/storyController")

    router.route("/")
        .get(storyController.findAll)
        .post(storyController.create);


    // api/story/:cat
    // find all stories with category
    router.route("/category/:cat")
        .get(storyController.findCat);

    // find a single story
    router.route("/top")
        .get(storyController.findOne);

    module.exports = router;
```

I'm expecting it to grab stories that have been posted in the database and show them on the page or allow someone to create a new user/login.   Instead, I just get a 404 error in the console:

```
xhr.js:166 GET https://ridonk-stories.herokuapp.com/api/story/ 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:166
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:49
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:56
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:71
wrap @ bind.js:11
getStory @ StoryAPI.js:9
StoriesOfTheDay.loadStories @ StoriesOfTheDay.js:22
componentDidMount @ StoriesOfTheDay.js:18
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:21142
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24138
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:363
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:412
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:466
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23903
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:674
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:11834
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:23723
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:22656
scheduleRootUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:25686
updateContainerAtExpirationTime @ react-dom.development.js:25712
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:25812
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26370
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:22952
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:26369
render @ react-dom.development.js:26460
./src/index.js @ index.js:17
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:786
fn @ bootstrap:149
0 @ setAuthToken.js:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:786
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
StoriesOfTheDay.js:24 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)`enter code here`
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

Heroku site: https://ridonk-stories.herokuapp.com/ViewStories
Github Repo: https://github.com/Toganas/TestingRidonk

Comment: i guess you need a GET methode inside api/story

Comment: I've got one.   let me update my post to reflect that

Comment: inside [this](https://github.com/Toganas/TestingRidonk/blob/master/client/src/actions/authActions.js) can you try this:

    `axios.post("https://ridonk-stories.herokuapp.com/api/users/login", userData)`

Instead of this :

    `axios.post("/api/users/login", userData)`

Comment: okay, I tried that and got: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
api/users/login:1 `   It doesn't expand this time though, it just says that.